# x64dbg break when hex string is loaded

Tags: debugging, x64dbg

I'm trying to break execution when a string is loaded in memory.

I can´t find the string by using the `search for -> string references`

So I press `Alt + M` and press `Ctrl + B` to search my string once is loaded, I can see it.
I try to right click on the address and set a hardware breakpoint but the software closes as soon as that string is shown so it doesn't break on the next run.

How can I set a condition so if a string appears a break happens?

I tried `shift + F4` like with ollydbg and then I try to create an expression like this `UNICODE[EAX] == "myString"` but it says `invalid expression...`

I also tried the same expression using traceInto, but it definitely is not matching for the string, because I can't see it int he dump and even if I compare with a huge string, it doesn't do anything at all.

Any suggestions or ideas?